# How to Loop through a Column of Cells and Concatenate Adjacent Cells into a New Cell?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, concatenation

I have two columns, one has a list of names and the other contains whether those names are "accepted" or "synonyms".

If a cell's value is "synonym" then I want to add the adjacent value from the first column to a blank cell followed by "; ".

As the program loops, I would like the following "synonym" names to be concatenated to the same cell, again followed by a semi colon and a space.

The code does not run.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     
    Dim y As Integer, acc As String, syn As String

    y = 159
    'acc is the blank cell for the concatenated strings
    acc = Cells(9, 158).Value
    syn = " "

    Do While y < 165
        If Cells(5, y).Value = "synonym" Then
            syn = Cells(4, y).Value
            acc = acc & syn.Value & "; "
        End If
       y = y + 1
   
   Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to return each value from the range `FC4:FH4` if the corresponding value in `FC5:FH5` is exactly `synonym` in a `"; "` separated list in cell `FB9`. Please confirm or provide info about what is wrong with the assumption.

Comment: Your assumption is mostly correct except... I want to return each value from the range D159:D165 if the corresponding value in E159:E165 is exactly "synonym" in a "; " separated list in cell I158 (the y coordinates are arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do Loop

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim acc As String
    Dim syn As String
    
    x = 159
    
    Do While x < 165
        If Cells(x, 5).Value = "synonym" Then
            syn = Cells(x, 4).Value
            acc = acc & "; " & syn
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    acc = Right(acc, Len(acc) - 2) ' "-2" the length of "; "
    Set rng = Cells(158, 9)
    rng.Value = acc

End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me a runtime error '5.' Invalid procedure call or argument. ```acc = Right(acc, Len(acc) - 2) ' "-2" the length of "; " ```

Comment: Sure, because the columns and rows were switched. Try this version.